# How to disable drag some element on ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I want to display name group on the top and cancel the  drag event on it.
How can I disable moving some element like if this group name on the top.
My code is:

```
dragulaService.drag.subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(`drag: ${value[0]}`);
});
```

My template :

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='container' *ngFor='let group of groups' [dragula]='"nested-bag"'>
     <div class="center-block">Table Number : {{group.name}}</div>
    <div *ngFor='let item of group.items' [innerHtml]='item.name'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

find a solution:

```
  dragulaService.setOptions('nested-bag', {
      revertOnSpill: true,
      moves: function (el:any, container:any, handle:any):any {
        debugger
        console.log(el, container);
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

To disable dragging element with specific class:

```
dragulaService.setOptions('PUT_CONTAINER_NAME_HERE', {
    moves: function (el: any, container: any, handle: any): any {
        if (el.classList.contains('PUT_YOUR_CLASS_HERE')) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: PUT_CONTAINER_NAME_HERE does this relate to the bag-name ?

Comment: `setOptions` is now `createGroup` for anyone using a more recent release

Answer (score 4):

Since [Version 2](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/blob/master/modules/ng2-dragula/CHANGELOG.md) (released 2018-07-19) you should use `dragulaService.createGroup()` instead of `dragulaService.setOptions()`:

```
dragulaService.createGroup('<container-name>', {
    moves: (el, container, handle, sibling) => false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add both functions(moves, accepts). Moves will prevent you to event start dragging the element. Accepts with sibling null will prevent other draggable elements trying to change position with the one is not in the model.

```
    dragulaService.setOptions('PUT_CONTAINER_NAME_HERE', {
    moves: function (el: any, container: any, handle: any): any {
        if (el.classList.contains('PUT_YOUR_CLASS_HERE')) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
      accepts: (el, target, source, sibling) => {
        if (sibling === null) {
          return false;
        }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative. You can use `invalid` instead of `moves`. Taken from the [documentation](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#optionsinvalid):

> You can provide an `invalid` method with a `(el, handle)` signature.
>   This method should return `true` for elements that shouldn't trigger a
>   drag. The `handle` argument is the element that was clicked, while
>   `el` is the item that would be dragged. Here's the default
>   implementation, which doesn't prevent any drags.
>
> ```
> function invalidTarget (el, handle) {
>   return false;
> }
> ```
>
> Note that `invalid` will be invoked on the DOM element that was
>   clicked and every parent up to immediate children of a `drake`
>   container.

Comment: This is the better more-universal answer for newest implementations