# Dragula disable drag to reorder

Tags: dragula, ng2-dragula

I am using this awesome library for drag and drop functionality.
Dragula is very good at drag and drop.

One thing I am trying to do is to disable dragging to reorder in own container. But should allow dragging if going to drop in a connected/linked container.

for example following two div tags as containers

```
<div dragula="dropContainer" id="dropbag1" [(dragulaModel)]="bagOneModel">
   <div *ngFor="let model of bagOneModel" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
     {{model}}
   </div>
</div>


<div dragula="dropContainer" id="dropbag2" [(dragulaModel)]="bag2Model">
   <div *ngFor="let model of bag2Model" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
     {{model}}
    <!-- don't allow re ordering in this container -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable drag some element on ng2-dragula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137782/how-to-disable-drag-some-element-on-ng2-dragula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to create something that permit to drag:

- from A to B
- from B to A
  and disable
- reorder inside A
- reorder inside B

In your `name.component.ts` you should add:

```
constructor(public dragulaService: DragulaService) {

    dragulaService.createGroup('dropContainer', {
        accepts: (el, target, source, sibling): boolean => {
            if (!target || !source || (target === source)) {
                 return false;
            }
            return true;
        }    
    });
}
```